# Unity - How can I make the snake to collect the food in order to get the score?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Actually, I am having a problem with the snake game I am developing.

The food does not collide with the snake "player", which does not destroy the game object. I  need your help, thanks!

Comment: Is `OnTriggerEnter2D` called if the player touches the food? Do you know how you can debug the code?

Comment: @Ackdari Yes, it is called. I have just put the debug.log and it says "Collides".

Answer (score 0):

Are these scripts at the food or at the snake? If the OnTriggerEnter2d is at the food, it should theoretically work. If it is at the snake, change it. Having said that, you can try a few things.

1. in the if statement, try this: collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")
2. Make sure there is a RigidBody2D component at the snake

Bonus TODO: Remove the GetComponent from the Update, it is a huge performance dump. Instead, create a method at the ScoringSystem that has a reference to the Text object and updates it when food is collected.

Comment: I am still having the same problem. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Also, I assume you have uncommented the line that actually Destroys the food, right? Because, you know, it is in comments here...

Comment: You are right! :D I was missing the Destroy Game object. Now the problem is that does not increase the score once the food is collected, it keeps getting 0.

Comment: We have progress. Now then, are you sure that the reference for the ScoringSystem is passed correctly? The easy way to check this out is this: Do you get a null pointer error? If you do, then this is the case.

Comment: void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)

   {
         //if (collision.tag == "Player")
        collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player");
        Debug.Log("Collides");
        {

         ScoringSystem.theScore += 1;

        // Destroy(collision.gameObject);
         }


    }

Comment: ScoringSystem is passed correctly when is called from the collection script.